# Error with ngCordova and socialsharing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Error:

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$window.plugins.socialsharing')
canShareVia@
```

HTML:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('PlayCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaSocialSharing) {

  $scope.shareAnywhere = function() {
        $cordovaSocialSharing.share("This is your message", "This is your subject", "www/imagefile.png", "https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com");
  }

  $scope.shareViaTwitter = function(message, image, link) {
        $cordovaSocialSharing.canShareVia("twitter", message, image, link).then(function(result) {
            $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaTwitter(message, image, link);
        }, function(error) {
            alert("Cannot share on Twitter");
        });
    }

})
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'chart.js','ngCordova'])
```

So I have installed cordova using (sudo npm install g-cordova) and used bower to install ng-cordova. I have added the socialshare plugin and all the files are located in the plugin folder of my ionic app's file directory.

I don't understand more else I need to do to get it to work :(

Comment: Check your folder tree. Is ng-cordova.js actually in "lib/ngCordova/dist"? Sometimes it gets installed somewhere else in a bower related directory.

Comment: Yes I checked...I did download cordova.js from github seperately but I put it in the correct location

Comment: Do i need to build out on ios/andriod for cordova to work...because I have not yet. Everything I am doing is testing on safari